# What is the precise optimizer model from the paper Optimization as a model for few-shot learning?

Tags: machine-learning, neural-networks, lstm, meta-learning

I was reading the paper [Optimization as a model for few-shot learning](https://openreview.net/pdf?id=rJY0-Kcll) and found the equations they provide are incomplete (or at least not informative enough to fill in some of the gaps). I was trying to understand what the role of the hidden state was in their model. Usually the forget gate is something like this:

$$ f^{<t>} = \sigma( W_F [ h^{<t-1>}, x^{<t>} ] + b_F )$$

but in their paper it's:

$$ f^{<t>} = \sigma( W_F [\nabla_{\theta} \mathcal L(\theta^{<t-1>}),\mathcal L^{<t>}, \theta^{<t>}, f^{<t-1>} ] + b^{<t>} ) $$

but in the equation from the paper there is no hidden state (so it's unclear what the hidden state actually is, but they mention it's there in writing so where is it in the equations?). Anyone know what it might be? Note that $c^{<t>} = \theta^{<t>}$ because of the matching they do between the update rule of their optimizer and a normal LSTM.

Answer (score 0):

After going through a [Pytorch implementation](https://github.com/markdtw/meta-learning-lstm-pytorch/blob/master/metalearner.py) I think this is the way to see their equations in pesudocode:

```
def forward_meta_learner(self, loss, grads , hs):

  ## first layer, normal LSTM, process raw inputs (grads,losses) and its previous hidden state & memory cell
  x^<t>_lstm = [loss^<t>, grads^<t>]
  h^<t-1>_lstm, c^<t-1>_lstm = hs.lstm
  # lstm forward
  h^<t>_lstm, c^<t>_lstm = self.lstm(input=x^<t>_lstm, hx=(h^<t-1>_lstm, c^<t-1>_lstm))
  ## second layer, optimizer/meta LSTM, produces new child/base model params theta^<t>
  x^<t>_metalstm = [h^<t>_lstm, grads]
  theta^<t-1>, f^<t-1>, i^<t-1> = hs.metalstm
  theta^<t>, h^<t>_metalstm = self.metalstm(input=x^<t>_metalstm, hx=(theta^<t-1>, f^<t-1>, i^<t-1>))

  ## prepare return statement
  hs.lstm = (h^<t>_lstm, c^<t>_lstm)
  hs.metalstm = (theta^<t>, f^<t>, i^<t>) = h^<t>_metalstm
  return theta^<t>, hs
```

so in high level, the first lstm takes in the losses and grads and preprocesses them. Then it produces a hidden state which is used as input to the meta-lstm (recall usual lstm, the hidden state and not the cell state is what is concatenated to the input x^ in all the gates and also the hidden state is what is used to produce the output e.g. what we softmax over so it makes sense to pass that as input to meta-lstm/optimizer lstm). Then those hidden states are passed to the next step in the first layer lstm. The second layer (meta-lstm) takes in the processed grads and produces an update according the the modified lstm equation:

$$ c^{<t>} = f^{<t>} \cdot c^{<t-1>} + i^{<t>} \cdot \tilde c^{<t>} $$
$$ \theta^{<t>} = f^{<t>} \cdot \theta^{<t-1>} - i^{<t>} \cdot \nabla_{\theta} \mathcal L(\theta^{<t-1>}) $$

Note: I suppressed the fact that the input to the first layer in fact does NOT receive grads, but preprocessed grads, for the sake of clarity of exposition.